# C autoreturn a value to "getch" after a short time

Tags: c

I am making "snake" from the console on C, I need to "autoreturn" a value to getch after a little time, I need to move the snake if the user doesn't press any key.

Comment: I don't think it's possible in standard C. You could use POSIX's `alarm` to break the call after a given period, but even that doesn't sound too well. Use `ncurses` and simply write a proper event loop.

Comment: Thanks, i will wait if someone other knows that. I am using getch to recive the direction of the snake

Comment: You mention `getch`. With MSVC you can use `kbhit` to detect if a key has been pressed before committing to `getch` (both non-standard).

Comment: Your best bet is to use a Curses library. For Windows, you may need to download the (new/now-active-again) [PDCurses](https://github.com/Bill-Gray/PDCurses) (also see the [PDCurses modified](https://www.projectpluto.com/win32a.htm) page); Linux and Mac and BSDs already have one (usually ncurses) in their repositories for you to use. Or you could just skip the console stuff, and go for [SDL](https://www.libsdl.org/). If you are using the outdated Borland compiler, don't; you won't learn the stuff you need in real life with that one.

Comment: XY problem. Why emulate a keypress? Just move the snake after some time. That is not related to input.

Comment: Because the user must say the direction of the snake, up-down-left-right. Anyway i found solution, thanks to Weather Vane,in my opinion is the easiest solution. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

The easiest method is to use kbhit to detect if a key has been pressed before committing to getch. In my case I used `if (kbhit()) getch();`